# Properties involving prime factorization and divisibility

Tags: divisibility, prime-factorization, unique-factorization-domains

Can anyone help me out this with proof?

> Let *n*  be a positive integer greater than 1 with the property that whenever *n* divides a product *ab* where a,b ∈ **Z**, then *n* divides *a* or *n* divides *b*. Prove that *n* is a prime number.

How would one effectively prove this? I don't know how to start this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Suppose $n$ is composite and try to produce integers $a,b > 1$ such that $n$ divides $ab$ but $n$ does not divide $a$ or $b$.

Comment: Well, if $n=ab$, then $n$ divides $ab$. Which divisors of $n$ are multiples of $n$ too?